# How to get FirstName + LastName from the user's google account authenticated using Asp.Identity in MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have created a MVC 5 application, and I'm able to authenticate the user using Google External login which is an out of box feature. I have observed that by authenticating the user using google account, UserName and Email are stored in database with the same value(i.e., Email for both of them). How do i retreive FirstName, LastName, from the registered google account.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get this inside the `ExternalLoginCallback` method in AccountController (as you are using out of the box project template) as explained below.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Google")
        {
                var externalIdentity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                var emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                var lastNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname);
                var givenNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName);

                var email = emailClaim.Value;
                var firstName = givenNameClaim.Value;
                var lastname = lastNameClaim.Value;
        }

     }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is worth to mention that this method is located in Controllers\AccountController.cs

Comment: @DSR Thanks a lot, very easy to integrate

Comment: I got here via searching not using MVC, but Microsoft Asp.Net Forms Identity Example Site .. the code is in "RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs"  Replace collection reference in above code to var externalIdentity = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);  to access the collection.